# Optional Password Confirmation Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

Is it possible to have AuthLogic validate a password confirmation if present, but otherwise ignore it? So, if my params are as following I'd like a failure:

```
{ user: { password: "abcd", password_confirmation: "defg" }
```

However if the parameters are instead as following I'd like a success:

```
{ user: { password: "abcdefgh" } }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not an AuthLogic's matter, this code should do the trick:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def update_without_password_confirmation(params={})
    params.delete(:password) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
    params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password].blank?

    update_attributes(params)
   end      
end
```

then call this method from controller when you need to update attributes on User. If User did not specify a password_confirmation, it will be ignored.
you can use several other techniques to get same effect, for example, using the before_validation(:on => :update) callback.

UPDATE: if you want to skip password validations at all, acts_as_authentic accepts a block to customize its behaviour:

```
clas User < AR::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |u|
    u.require_password_confirmation=false # you can also use :if => some_condition
    u.validate_password_field=false
  end
end
```

this is a bit un-documented :P check this file:
https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/password.rb

Comment: Any way to switch it so that a general 'update' or 'create' will work? I'd really like this application wide.

Answer (score -1):

```
before_validate :check_password_confirmation
def check_password_confirmation
  if self.password_confirmation.blank?
    self.password = nil
  end
end
```

With the added benefit that you don't have to worry about setting or unsetting things in your controllers - the model continues to update_attributes normally.